# How can I embed opensans font in UWP application

Tags: uwp-xaml

How can I embed opensans font in UWP application. In my system it work properly but when I using another system the font is not reflected. Currently this way I am using font `Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf#Open Sans`. I am WPF developer, in WPF we are using `pack` to embed the font. Is their any way to embed font in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I embed opensans font in UWP application

For using custom font in uwp

After you choose the font you like, download its `.ttf` or `.otf` file and add it into your UWP app project as a **Content** file.

[image]

**Setting the font in XAML**

You need use font family with this format `FontFamily="[FontFilePath]#[FontName]"`.

Example:

```
FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/ArimaMadurai-Black.ttf#Arima Madurai Black"
```